# React Redux, how change a single element inside a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have a question for you.. i have an object stored in my redux store, this object contains other object and array of object.. So, i need to update a single field inside this object and mantain the entire object and after i'll make a post request by passing this object.

My object (payload) is:

```
{
name: "test",
surname: " test2",
option: [
{
option1: "option1"
}}
]
additionalInfo: {
location: "street"
}
```

each element are printend in page using input text field,
how i can make a function that onchange method selecte the correct field and update it?

```
function policies(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case policiesTypes.SET_POLICY_DETAILS:  
      return { ...state, content: payload };
```

Comment: Can you please show your reducer with your current attempt so that we have something to build off of?

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispatch the store. use `store.dispatch` in onChange written as a function. This will help you change the store's global state. And in the reducer's switch, it is `switch(action)` and action object holds `action.type` and `action.payload`. When you directly pass action type in the switch statement, you might not get results as expected.

eg :
    In your Reducer change the switch statement as:

```
switch(action){
case "YOUR_ACTION":
  return {...state, ...action.payload};
}
```

> In your index.js file,

```
import store from 'react-redux';
...

onChange=(value)=>{
   store.dispatch({type:"YOUR_ACTION",payload:value});
}
```

This will clear the existing object's values and update the state with the new values that you provide. And as you are updating onChange, the state might clear all previous keys too, so be cautious while using it onChange.

Comment: But this will cancel my old store, i need only to change an attribute or key, for example additionalInfo.location and keep the rest of the state that has not been updated.. and the value for me is the e.target.value or when you press on the save button update the state

Comment: Learn about spread operator in JavaScript. And if you're still confused then try this in your swtich case--, `return {...state, name : action.payload.name, surname: action.payload.surname}` This will update the state for sure, it won't cancel your existing state.

Comment: what i need to do is different:

`onChange={(e) => dispatch(actions.prepareToSavePolicy({ policyHeader: { riskGrading: e.target.value } }))}`

    `case policiesTypes.PREPARE_TO_SAVE_UPDATED_POLICY:
      return { ...state, updatedPolicy: {...state.updatedPolicy, payload} };`

store is updated, but the old data is cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Solved from myself:

```
case policiesTypes.SET_POLICY_HEADER:
  let content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.content));
  content.policyHeader = content.policyHeader || {};
  content.policyHeader[action.key] = action.value;
  return { ...state,  content};
```

and actions:

```
const setPolicyHeader = (key, value) => ({type: policiesTypes.SET_POLICY_HEADER, key, value});
```

and onchange

```
onChange={ e => dispatch(actions.setPolicyHeader('localPolicyNumber', e.target.value))}
```